# Custom section/collection in Web.Config

Tags: c#, web-config, custom-attributes

I've got a bunch of routes that I want to be able to throw in my Web.Config file. I need one key and two value fields for each section/item in the collection. Something along the lines of this...

```
<routes>
    <add
        key="AdministrationDefault"
        url="Administration/"
        file="~Administration/Default.aspx" />

    <add
        key="AdministrationCreateCampaign"
        url="Administration/CreateCampaign/"
        file="~/Administration/CreateCampaign.aspx" />

    <add
        key="AdministrationLogout"
        url="Administration/Leave/"
        file="~/Administration/Leave.aspx" />
</routes>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. And not too hard once you have a start.

You'll need to create a `ConfigurationSection` derived class to define the `<routes>` section (and then add a `<section>` to the configuration to link the  `<routes>` element to your type).

You'll then need a type to define each element of the collection and, flagged as default, a property on your second type for the collection.

After all this is set up, at runtime you access your configuration section as:

```
var myRoutes = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("routes") as RoutesConfigSection;
```

My blog has a few articles on the background to this: http://blog.rjcox.co.uk/category/dev/net-core/

As noted in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738178/custom-section-collection-in-web-config/7738238#7738238) there is also coverage (a lot better than it used to be) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create a class to represent your config section you can do this:

```
var configSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("sectionGroup/sectionName");
var aValue = (configSection as dynamic)["ValueKey"];
```

Converting to dynamic lets you access the key values in configSection. You may have to add a break point and peak in configSection to see what is there and what ValueKey to use.

Comment: It doesn't works. It throw the "The configuration section cannot be read because it is missing schema"