# DllImport from class library or web service project

Tags: c#, asp.net, dllimport

I created a console application to import "C" Dll using DllImport
The "C" Dll has reference to other Dll's and Config files in same folder.

When i put all the files in bin directory of Console applicaiton it works perfect.

But when i create a Web application to consume the same it does not work. (The dll reference are fine when i set the path, but it seems the config files are not getting loaded)

I have tried below but did not help.

1. Copy the DLL's and config files to System32.
2. Give access permission to IIS.
3. Disable shadow copy.

None seem to work, Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are the config files in the same directory as the managed DLLs of your ASP.Net application?

Comment: Yes both managed and unmanaged dll's along with unmanaged dll's config are in same folder

Comment: Have you tried to reference the config files from your project and mark them as "copy always"?

Comment: Yes the config files and dll's are part of my project marked with copy always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue.

I used `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory();` to set the path of the dll's and config files.

if its not possible to change the current directory. Place the files in path `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to move the configuration into the web.config file for the web application
There's some good advice on how to do that here: [Custom section/collection in Web.Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738178/custom-section-collection-in-web-config)

Comment: The config files are used by unmanaged dll's. How can i move them to web.config.